# Is the empty tuple denoted by () a empty function f: ∅- > ∅?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory, set-theory

[image]

I'm studying a book analysis 1 by T.Tao and I have three questions.

what i wrote as Title is the first one and the rests are these.

1.Does the empty tuple denoted by () mean a empty function f: Ø → Ø ?

2. Is an ordered n-tuple of sets (X_i)1≤i≤n always needed when defining a n-fold Cartesian product?
3. If the answer to the number 2 question is true then I need an ordered tuple of sets (X_i)1≤i≤0 to define a Cartesian product ⫪(X_i)1≤i≤0.

but what is this ordered tuple of sets (X_i)1≤i≤0 ?

I asked the author on his blog but he replied all other questions except mine ㅜㅜ

Are these silly questions?

anyway please help..

Comment: Your posts are much more inviting if you had used MathJax. Please introduce yourself & do so! Here's a [worthwhile link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: 1. Yes; 2. Yes; 3. So when $n=0$ it just holds that $\{1\le i\le 0\}=\varnothing$, so it suffices to just consider empty tuples.

Answer (score 0):

1. The definition of "empty tuple" is in Example 3.5.11 of the text. The empty tuple is the only element in the "empty Cartesian product $\prod_{1\le i\le 0} X_i$.
2. It is not that the n-tuple is "needed" but that it is "by definition" an element of the Cartesian product. See Definition of 3.5.7.
3. No.